# How do I copy a remote branch on GitHub into a new remote branch?

Tags: git, github

Specifically, I never want the new branch to exist on my hard drive. I just want my existing branch *develop* copied into a new branch on GitHub called *meow*

Comment: And you don't want to use the website?

Comment: I can't see an easy way to do this in the GitHub interface?

Comment: Click on Branch dropdown, there is a textbox "Find or create branch", write the name and there will be an option "Create branch: meow"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's ok to do it on the website, go to the repository, open the branch dropdown. There is a textbox *Find or create branch*. Write the name, there will be a selection *Create branch: meow*. Click on that and you have a new branch off your selected branch.

Comment: ...and how about if I want to import a branch from the parent github repo, so I can merge not-yet-approved fixes?! :D

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I found out how to do this on BitBucket. It should be very similar though.

1. Go to `bitbucket.org` and go to your project.
2. Under Navigation, on the left side, go to the `Branches tab`.
3. Click create branch, make sure that the Branch from specifies `develop`.
4. Specify your new branch name (`meow`).
5. Click `create`.
6. Go to the server command line.
7. Make a new directory. This is where the content of the new branch branch will be located.
8. Go into that new directory
9. Execute the command: `git init`
      -This will initialize an empty repository, telling git that we will either create a new project here or get an existing project
10. Execute the command: `git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:(repositoryName)/(branchName).git`

    -This tells git that we will be using an existing project. The location of the project is bitbucket.org:repo… And we will use the username, git, to get this project.

    -The above link can also be found on the page after you created your new branch
11. Execute the command: `git fetch && git checkout meow`

    -This will download new branch which should already contain a copy of develop source.